# Simplecov evaluating files twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-coverage, jruby, minitest, simplecov

I am attempting to add code coverage to my rails application, and want to do get overall coverage numbers for my Unit, functional and selenium tests. I am using minitest and jruby 1.7.19 (if that matters), and starting Simplecov in an initializer file.

In the report I am noticing that the same file is evaluated twice, but one has 0% coverage and the other has some percentage of coverage. This is throwing off the overall coverage numbers.

The 2 identical files in the report look like this:

```
lib/qa/psd_components/tools.rb
lib//qa/psd_components/tools.rb
```

notice the extra forward slash after lib in the second, which seems to be causing simplecov to treat it as a different file. I am not sure why this is happening.